# Amazon Selling Partner API - signed request (ruby implementation)

Tags: ruby, amazon-product-api

Following the Amazon Selling Partner API Doc, I was able to get the `LWA access token`.
However, I'm getting blocked in making request to the REST API.

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api

I tried to use `aws-sdk-signer` to create a signed request

```
access_token = 'LWA access token'

signer = Aws::Sigv4::Signer.new(
  access_key_id: 'my access id',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  secret_access_key: 'my access key,
  service: 'execute-api',
)

signature = signer.sign_request(
  http_method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders',
  headers: {
    'host' => 'sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com',
    'user_agent' => 'test (Language=Ruby)',
    'x-amz-access-token' => access_token
  })

response = HTTParty.send(:get, 'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders', headers: {
  'host' => signature.headers['host'],
  'user_agent' => 'test (Language=Ruby)',
  'x-amz-access-token' => access_token,
  'x-amz-content-sha256' => signature.headers['x-amz-content-sha256'],
  'x-amz-date' => signature.headers['x-amz-date'],
  'Authorization' => signature.headers['authorization'],
})
```

resposne

```
{"errors"=>[{"message"=>"Access to requested resource is denied.", "code"=>"Unauthorized", "details"=>"Access token is missing in the request header."}]}
```

It looks like I'm not signing the LWA access token correctly, but I have no idea what's going on since this is a new API and there's not much implementation especially in ruby.

Would anyone give some directions?

Update: I followed the Singer document
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Sigv4/Signer.html

[Aws::Sigv4::Signer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVoFL.png)

Comment: What are you getting for `signature.headers`?  Are the values of this hash accessible in plaintext?  I think the signature in `'x-amz-content-sha256'` is supposed to be a hashed result representing the values of the entire request.

Comment: `signature.headers` returns plain text string, ref from the document 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Sigv4/Signature.html

In the example, the `'x-amz-content-sha256'` is `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`

Comment: Hmm, check the docs to see what the headers should look like.  e.g. Authorization headers should look like this: `Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIDEXAMPLE/20150830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html
  https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#step-3-add-headers-to-the-uri

Comment: thanks for reply! I sent the `Authoriazation` here
 `'Authorization' => signature.headers['authorization']` which looks like `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAUDJT3KUQIRIKGDW6/20210112/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;user_agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=bfdcceb3f4a8f33120b59a0f0d07cf62456fb5f88d5823cc739e9516c7ef6728`

Comment: Actually, I'm confused about `x-amz-content-sha256` since the document didn't mention this header. However, the AWS Signer automatically signed this header by default.

Comment: I'm also facing the same 'unauthorized' issue. Can you able to access sandbox data atlease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this:

Your problem likely stems from `HTTParty` (or other HTTP client gems) using Ruby's `Net::HTTPHeader` behind the scenes.

`Net::HTTPHeader` capitalizes all request headers before the request is sent and the `x-amz-access-token` header is case-sensitive.

If you're populating `x-amz-access-token` with a valid value and still receiving the following error:

```json
{
    "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "details": "Access token is missing in the request header."
}
```

...then you're likely running into this issue.

You can bypass this by overloading `Net:HTTPHeader.capitalize` like so:

```rb
module Net::HTTPHeader
  def capitalize(name)
    name
  end
  private :capitalize
end
```

see also: https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/292#issuecomment-759904882

Answer (score 0):

"Access token is missing in the request header" sounds like something is wrong with your x-amz-access-token. Are you retrieving it like this? https://github.com/ericcj/amz_sp_api/blob/main/lib/sp_api_client.rb#L40